# Can't get cx_Oracle to work with Python version 2.7 / mac os 10.7.2 (Lion) - missing_OCIAttrGet

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Can't get cx_Oracle to work with Python version 2.7 / mac os 10.7.2 (Lion)

One other thing: I have installed oracle 32 bit, not sure if that was correct.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "reader.py", line 9, in <module>
        import cx_Oracle
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/cx_Oracle.py", line 7, in <module>
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/cx_Oracle.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/.python-eggs/cx_Oracle-5.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Symbol not found: _OCIAttrGet
      Referenced from: /Users/me/.python-eggs/cx_Oracle-5.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/cx_Oracle.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /Users/me/.python-eggs/cx_Oracle-5.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/cx_Oracle.so
```

They key problem seems to be not being able to locate `_OCIAttGet`, and I think this means that it cant find a lib file or something.

Found on the web, someone talking about `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but mine is set, however he mentioned it in `cxoracle.cfg` file, that I can not locate, is this my problem?

*EDIT*

After trying to run it with 32 bit mode python, I see a different error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "reader.py", line 9, in <module>
     import cx_Oracle
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/cx_Oracle.py", line 7, in <module>
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/cx_Oracle.py", line 3, in __bootstrap__
 ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

- I could not get the oracle 64 bit versions to run on my computer, kept getting segmentation faults when i ran sqlplus, so thats why I am using the 32.

*SECOND EDIT*

Actually no matter what i install, it is not the right version.. 32 bit version

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/oracle/instantclient10_2/libclntsh.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

64 bit version:

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/oracle/instantclient10_2/libclntsh.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

I am going to try 11g, but that only has a 64 bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Apple-supplied Python 2.7, it will prefer to run in 64-bit mode and that will be a problem if you did install 32-bit-only Oracle libraries.  You can try forcing that Python to run in 32-bit mode by starting it this way:

```
arch -i386 python2.7
```

If you are careful to always launch python via `/usr/bin/python`, you could also use either of the methods described in Apple's `man` page for Python, i.e. setting a `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` environment variable or setting a permanent default via `defaults`.

Comment: I got then when i reinstalled cx_Oracle with PIPld: warning: ignoring file /opt/oracle/instantclient10_2/libclntsh.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Comment: But does it work despite the warning message? Sometimes there are confusing messages because OS X universal files contain executables for multiple architectures in the same file.

Comment: no, the python still fails with the same error.
  Symbol not found: _OCIAttrGet
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so

Comment: Using `arch -i386 python2.7` gives me the same error as @nycynik. However, exporting the `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` variable and simply using `python` works for me.

Comment: Thanks, this made me realize I had mistakenly downloaded the 32 bit libraries when I need the 64 bit one (OSX 10.11.2). Once I re-downloaded the 64 bit ones (basic+sdk), I had to do `pip uninstall cx_Oracle` and reinstall it. After that, it works great.

Answer (score 7):

To [compile cx_Oracle so it'll work on OS X](http://mechanicalcat.net/richard/log/Python/Compiling_cx_Oracle_on_OS_X) needs a couple of things configured. The important bits are:

1. Create a virtualenv with a python interpreter stripped to 32-bit only. In the virtualenv bin directory (`$WORKON_HOME/*name_of_virtualenv*/bin`):

   ```
   % mv python python.fat
   % lipo python.fat -remove x86_64 -output python
   ```
2. Even though Python is now thin its configuration is not so we need to force things using an obscure environment variable that distutils will pick up:

   ```
   ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" pip install cx_Oracle
   ```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem, banged my head against this too long.

Comment: This is great, because it works for running servers that run python on their own (like flask.)

Answer (score 2):

Steps to install to oracle client on mac ox 10.8.5 for connecting oracle from python. (There is bug due to it 64 bit doesn't work for mac ox 10.8.5 )

1. Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html
2. Download instantclient-basic-macos.x32-11.2.0.3.0.zip
3. Download instantclient-sdk-macos.x32-11.2.0.3.0.zip
4. Create new folder under /Users/< your username>/ora_32(you can name what you want )
5. Move the zip files instantclient-sdk-macos.x32-11.2.0.3.0.zip  and 
   instantclient-basic-macos.x32-11.2.0.3.0.zip to 
   /Users/< your username>/ora_32 Command below

   ```
   mv insta*32* /Users/< your username>/ora_32/
   ```
6. Unzip instantclient-basic-macos.x32-11.2.0.3.0.zip and 
   instantclient-sdk-macos.x32-11.2.0.3.0.zip 
   Command below

   ```
   cd /Users/< your username>/ora_32/
   unzip instantclient-basic-macos.x32-11.2.0.3.0.zip
   unzip instantclient-sdk-macos.x32-11.2.0.3.0.zip
   ```
7. it will create a folder instantclient_11_2 under 
    /Users//ora_32/
8. cd to /Users/< your username>/ora_32/instantclient_11_2
   and Create the below symbolic link which
   will be used in the installation of cx_Oracle.( Mentioned below )

   ```
   ln -s libclntsh.dylib.11.1 libclntsh.dylib
   ln -s libocci.dylib.11.1 libocci.dylib
   ```
9. Export the environment variables for the current session
   or you can add them in bash profile to invoke every time you open
   a new terminal.

   ```
   export ORACLE_HOME=/Users/<your username>/ora_32/instantclient_11_2
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
   export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
   export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<your username>/ora_32/instantclient_11_2
   ```
10. Download cx_Oracle (option source code only) 
    at the link http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net
11. Untar the cx_Oracle tar file and it will create a cx_Oracle-5.1.2 folder
    cd to that folder cx_Oracle-5.1.2
12. Run the below command it will install cx_Oracle and then

    ```
     sudo easy_install cx_Oracle
    ```
13. You can check by going to python prompt and typing import cx_Oracle

Comment: What do you mean 'option source code only'?  I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: Most of the installation steps I followed are similar, yet I got an error. The missing step was export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<your username>/ora_32/instantclient_11_2

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if you're still having problems with this, but here is how I got it to work.

I followed the instructions listed here (using the 32-bit downloads from Oracle):
http://www.xairon.net/2011/05/guide-installing-cx_oracle-on-mac-os-x/

I then had the same error you listed:

> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Symbol not found: _OCIAttrGet
>    Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
>    Expected in: flat namespace
>   in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so

The problem was from Apple's Python distribution running in 64-bit mode by default.

Once I forced the Apple supplied Python to use 32-bit (from Ned's recommendation), it worked!

To do that:

> $export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=Yes

To make it permanent:

> $defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes

Comment: I am still having this problem!  Thank you, will try it!

Comment: It may be helpful to explicitly check if you're running 64-bit Python or 32-bit Python. Use the techniques listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode) to do so.

Comment: Thank you @NathanJones!  That did it.  Even when I export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=Yes I was actually still running python in 64bit mode.  When I used "arch -i386 python" it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.3.

After 4 hours of trying various solutions, I finally realized that this was the result of having installed the 32-bit version of Oracle InstantClient, which conflicted with the 64-bit version of python.

To resolve: I uninstalled python (and some dependencies), then reinstalled the universal version.  I followed the directions in this post to strip the x86_64 from the python binary in my virtualenv.  This allowed the 32-bit Oracle InstantClient to work with the 32-bit python binary.

I am hesitant to use the 64-bit Oracle InstantClient, due to some other posts I saw while researching this issue.