# cx_Oracle on Mac OS Lion

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, cx-oracle

I made steps as described here
http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csSpring2011/cs327/cx_mac.html
and installed cx_Oracle on Mac OS Lion x64

import cx_Oracle – done successfully

But when I try to use it – I get an error window:

> Python quit unexpectedly while using the libclntsh.dylib.10.1 plug-in

and error message in terminal:

> Segmentation fault: 11

Does anybody know how to repair it?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to get cx_Oracle to work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452731/182097

Hope this helps!